# Magento base url issue with MAMP Pro

Tags: php, magento, mamp-pro

I have a Magento website that I have cloned to my local machine running through `MAMP Pro` with a custom host name e.g: project.local

The issue is, the is a function in the file:

`app/design/frontend/default/project/template/page/html/head.phtml`

which includes a number of `css/js` files however the include path seems to be wrong using the base url/directory: **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/** which results in the files not being found. The function is:

```
$this->getCssJsHtml()
```

Here is a list of the files in question which I have taken from the source:

http://i.xomf.com/dcmsw.png

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/css/styles.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/base/default/css/bubble/elasticsearch.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/inchoo_socialconnect/google/css/button.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/inchoo_socialconnect/facebook/css/button.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/css/ajax-cart.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/css/tablet.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/css/ie_10.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/css/print.css" media="print" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery.noconflict.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery.joypopup.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/varien/js.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/varien/form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/mage/translate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/quickbuy.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/topmenu.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/event.simulate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/html5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/ajax_cart.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery.CustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery.selectbox-0.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery.maketabs.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery.instagram.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery.minitwitter.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery/jquery.jqzoom-core-pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/social_login.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/utagtracking.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/skin/frontend/default/theme_name/js/play_video.js"></script>
```

Just to be clear, these are the only places that are effected. The other includes seem to relate to the base url set in the database: `core_config_data`.

I'm not sure if this is anything to do with MAMP Pro and the Virtual Hosts set-up, but needless to say I have tried everything I can after searching many... many hours on the internet for a solution with no success.

I would appreciate any help, thanks again in advance.

Comment: Can you got to admin -> System -> Configuration -> Web and in Unsecure and Secure tab, confirm that you have correct urls set for skin and js folders?

Comment: Hi @AltafHussain I'm trying your suggestion: http://i.xomf.com/jjmfb.png ... figuring out where to go when it looks like this..

Comment: Looks good to me: http://i.xomf.com/fddjn.png

Comment: :P , it is the urls issue. Go to your database and then core_config_data and find these paths: web/unsecure/base_skin_url, web/unsecure/base_js_url, web/unsecure/base_media_url, web/secure/base_link_url, web/secure/base_skin_url, web/secure/base_media_url,  web/secure/base_js_url   and see they are correct

Comment: Can you check in database and see if you have different urls for each store view? Because those settings seems fine.

Comment: Here is a screenshot showing the values of the fields you mentioned above: http://i.xomf.com/qfhhz.png they look file to me.

Comment: Where in the database would I check the URL's for the store view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically simple problem, have you cleared js/css cache.  This happens often when the server is moved from one location to the next because the directory path is cached when merged.  Disabling Merge JS and Css files in system->developer javascript and css settings will correct the problem however you have to do some front-end hackery in order to actually save the value.

A way to verify this problem is to run the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM `core_config_data`
WHERE `path` LIKE '%merge%
```

If these values are set to 1 this will cause your problem, much easier to disable set to "0" this value via Database directly considering you have access. Then Clear Magento cache including JS / CSS cache and this should resolve your problem

Screen shot of what this should look like:

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Thank you very much for your answer, everything worked as you suggested above. The backend javascript save functionality was not functioning but changing the values in the database to 0 worked just the same. @Rob karma++